# passing variables to a template on a redirect in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, jinja2

I am relatively new to Python so please excuse any naive questions.

I have a home page with 2 inputs, one for a "product" and one for an "email." When a user clicks submit they should be sent to "/success" where it will say:
You have requested "product"
You will be notified at "email"

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass the "product" and "email" values through the redirect into my "/success" template. I am using webapp2 framework and jinja within Google App Enginge.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do your redirect, include your email and product variables in the redirect. In Google appp engine, using webapp2, your current redirect probably looks like:

```
self.redirect('/sucess')
```

Instead, you can add the variables in the URL as follows:

```
self.redirect('/success?email=' + email + '&product=' + product)
```

The above URL would look like '/success?email=this@email.com&product=this_product' after concatenating the values.

The handler for /success could then get those values with:

```
email = self.request.get('email')
product = self.request.get('product')
```

Comment: @Aaron, is this way secure enough? i mean passing the variables through the URL ?

Comment: @mazlor For what the original poster needed, yes, this is secure enough.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use HTML forms, the POST request for submitting the form should include the values on the submit.

Comment: like i said, im very new to this. can you elaborate?