# How to cache frequently used data in-process, in a GAE application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

In Google App Engine, one cannot store (as a whole) an object larger than 1 MB in `memcache`.

Say I want to cache the results of a datastore query, which consists of 1000 records of 5 KB each - with a total of ~5 MB.

How to proceed? Can I cache this data in the Python process of my web application, instead of using `memcache`? For example, in a global variable?

*Please find my answer below. Let me know what you think.*

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine may resolve different web requests to different processes or even different physical machines. Which means that it's a bit harder to maintain global state among different requests, that is, to implement *local* caches of the data.

When data modifications happen, you have to be careful to invalidate the local caches - on all processes (*cache coherence* issue).

Furthermore, if your GAE application is defined as `threadsafe`, a single process could handle multiple requests at the same time, in different threads.

I sketched a possible solution:

- keep the data in-process using a global dictionary
- keep track of the version of the in-process data using a global dictionary
- keep the *gold* version of the data in a tiny `memcache` record (only the version tag, not the actual data, of course)
- when in-process local data is stale (invalid), fetch it from the *gold* storage (via the `value_provider` function)
- when appropriate, invalidate in-process data among all machines (by resetting the *gold* version tag).

Here is the code:

```
import threading
from uuid import uuid4
from google.appengine.api import memcache

_data = dict()
_versions = dict()
lock = threading.Lock()

TIME = 60 * 10  # 10 minutes


def get(key, value_provider):
    """
    Gets a value from the in-process storage (cache).
    If the value is not available in the in-process storage
    or it is invalid (stale), then it is fetched by calling the 'value provider'.
    """
    # Fast check, read-only step (no critical section).
    if _is_valid(key):
        return _data[key]

    # Data is stale (invalid). Perform read+write step (critical section).
    with lock:
        # Check again in case another thread just left the critical section
        # and brought the in-process data to a valid state.
        if _is_valid(key):
            return _data[key]

        version = memcache.get(key)

        # If memcache entry is not initialized
        if not version:
            version = uuid4()
            memcache.set(key, version, time=TIME)

        _data[key] = value_provider()
        _versions[key] = version

    return _data[key]


def _is_valid(key):
    """Whether the in-process data has the latest version (according to memcache entry)."""
    memcache_version = memcache.get(key)
    proc_version = _versions.get(key, None)
    return memcache_version and memcache_version == proc_version


def invalidate(key):
    """Invalidates the in-process cache for all processes."""
    memcache.set(key, uuid4(), time=TIME)
```

**References:**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/222818

[Understanding global object persistence in Python WSGI apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8170973/1475331)

[Problem declaring global variable in python/GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621259/1475331)

[Python Threads - Critical Section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419145/1475331)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence